# How to use GStreamer to stream from IP RTMP Camera to v4l2loopback Camera?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gstreamer, rtmp, v4l2

I am trying to use GStreamer to connect RTMP/RTSP stream to a v4l2loopback Virtual Device.

**Works 1 - RTMP to AutoVideoSink**

sudo gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.xxx.xxx/live/av0 ! decodebin ! autovideosink

sudo gst-launch-1.0 rtmpsrc location=rtmp://192.168.xxx.xxx/live/av0 ! decodebin ! autovideosink

**Works 2 - TestSrc to Dummy Video5**

sudo gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video5

**Does not work - RTMP to Dummy Video5 – No error but does not show the video**

sudo gst-launch-1.0  rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.xxx.xxx/live/av0  do-timestamp=true 
protocols="tcp" ! rtph264depay  ! h264parse  ! decodebin   ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video5

I highly suspect there are some parameters of Gstreamer that are required and I am unaware of. 
Because the log file has a lot of entries on unknown pixel format, default values, etc.

Please could you give me some pointers of which parameters to set?

The source is a high-quality PTZ camera which supports either RTMP and RTSP.

The sink is V4L2 loopback device.

Answer (score 1):

You might need a `videoconvert` after the `decodebin`

Try running your pipeline with `GST_DEBUG=3` and that will give you more info on why caps negotiation failed!